# How do I locate packages in Eclipse IDE (c++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, package

guys it's ok I solved this problem already ignore everything:

I am new to c++ and I am using Eclipse IDE. So I created a new project and wanted to use some packages:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>
```

but the first packages would not import. Then I realized that I have not downloaded that package yet. So I went to https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/ to download it. but after It finished downloading. It still shows the error. How do I import the package? Or did I download it incorrectly?

[image: a picture of my error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the picture - which should be copied into the question as plain text - tells that your cpp does not have a `main()` function. In C++, you have to have a `main()` function. I suggest you read a book or tutorial on C++ while trying it out, as it's way easier that way.

You need, *for the next step*:

```
int main() {
}
```

But, to develop an actual SFML-based program, you'll need much more.

Comment: why when I added
int main() {

}
it still shows the error from the screenshot?

Comment: @Coding_Guy Please type the _exact_ text of the error shown afterwards.

Comment: it's ok I fixed the problem. I changed an IDE